# Preventing a NestedScrollView from scrolling parent NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview, nestedscrollview, android-touch-event

I have a `NestedScrollView`(NSVchild), inside a horizontal `RecyclerView`, inside another `NestedScrollView`(NSVparent). Inside NSVchild is a `TextView` with long texts.

What I want to know now is, how can I prevent NSVchild from scrolling NSVparent, when NSVchild finishes scrolling from top or bottom?

#### What I tried:

I tried extending `NestedScrollView`, and overriding `onTouchEvent`, and returning false when NSVchild is at `scroll` 0 and user is dragging down on the screen, and when NSVchild is at it's max `scroll` and user is dragging up. Returning `false` works as expected, but problem is understanding when user is dragging up or down on the screen. here's is the code for that:

```
float deltaY = 0;
float oldY = 0;
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float y = ev.getY();
                deltaY = y - oldY;
                oldY = y;
                Log.i("deltaY", deltaY+"");
                break;
        }
    [...]
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

in this approach, `deltaY < 0` means that screen is being dragged upwards, and `deltaY > 0` means vice versa. It works well as long as there's room for NSVchild to scroll inside itself. when it finishes scrolling from one side, and starts scrolling NSVparent, `deltaY` will become less than 0 in one frame, and in the next, more than 0, And this makes my code useless.

Is there any other way to achieve what I want? Or a better way to understand if screen is being dragged up or down?